# scp/rsync hangs when trying to connect to a very old Mac

Tags: ssh, leopard, rsync

I am trying to transfer files from an ancient Mac (OS 10.5.8) that has not been upgraded for years to a new (Ventura 13.3.1) machine and find that scp and rsync don't work. The old Mac is visible in my home network, and yesterday I was still able to transfer files with
`scp -r -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa myuser@oldmac.local:Desktop/transfer .`

Today this didn't work anymore after trying unsuccessfully to rsync files from the new machine to the old one. rsync always hangs with no error messages (in spite of using `-v`), and scp now also simply hangs.
What's going on, and how can I fix it and at least transfer files between the machines?

Comment: Did you restart both Macs to start from a clear state? If it still doesn't work after that, run `ssh -vvv ...` to get some more diagnostics and add the relevant part of the output to the question (copy/paste as text, format as code).

Comment: I restarted the receiving (old) Mac now and find that scp works again, but rsync still hangs and seems to trigger something on the old Mac that makes a renewed scp hang as well. The rsync command I tried is `rsync -rvu -e "ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -l myuser" srcdir myuser@oldmac.local:targetdir`. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: Please run `ssh -vvv ...` to get more info. Something is obviously stuck, without more details we can't know what.

Comment: `debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to oldmac.local port 22.
`

Comment: It's usually easier if you edit the question to add the output, too much details get lost in comments. But it looks as if sshd on the old Mac is stuck. Is there anything useful in the log files of the old Mac (`/var/log/system.log`)? Can you deactivate and reactive ssh on the old Mac via Preferences and try again?

Comment: Also, if you reboot the old Mac again and then try to log in several times via ssh (without rsync inbetween), do all the logins work or only the first one?

Comment: Yes, several logins are possible if I don't forget to use the `-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa`option; once I forget it, ssh hangs, and I can't login anymore, even if I use the option again in the next attempt. I can restart the ssh on the old mac from the System Preferences, and then remote login is possible again.
In the logfile I haven't seen much related to ssh, only something mentioning an `Unknown key: SHAuthorizationRight` that seems to pop up when the service is started.
It seems that I must somehow tell rsync how to build the connection with that ssh-rsa option.